# Why is libGPIOd not working on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

I am trying to communicate via GPIO using C. Based on [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101718/control-gpio-pins-from-c) I tried to download the source for libgpiod and build but I got...

> configure: error: "libgpiod needs linux headers version >= v5.5.0"

I tried to install via aptitude like `sudo apt-get install libgpiod` but when I run `sudo gpioget gpiochip1 20`(GPIO 20 works on my python app) I get...

> gpioget: error reading GPIO values: Invalid argument

How do I get libgpiod to work? Is there a more "native" way to do GPIO programming?

Answer (score 5):

See my more complete answer at the link below

[Control GPIO pins from C](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101718/control-gpio-pins-from-c/111719#111719)

But to summarize the setup that worked for me:

Raspberry Pi 3B (but I suspect this will work for RPi 4 as well).

Clean install of buster. Installing gpiod on jessie failed for me.

```
sudo apt-get install gpiod libgpiod-dev libgpiod-doc
```

The standalone applications

```
gpiodetect, gpioinfo, gpioget, gpioset, gpiofind and gpiomon
```

are installed along with two different C APIs.

API 1) Found in /usr/include/linux/gpio.h and included via:

```
#include <linux/gpio.h>
```

Note that you also need to include several system call libraries.

API 2) Found in /usr/include/gpiod.h (and gpiod.hpp for C++), and included via:

```
#include <gpiod.h>
```

I believe that installing this API is the one that also brings in the standalone apps. Programs using this API need to be compiled with something like:

```
gcc -o myprogram -lgpiod myprogram.c
```

My other contribution gives an example of API 1, as well as some links to other examples.